# How do I add a person to a mysql json array?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a json array in mysql with 2 persons like this

```
{"people": [
            {"lastname": "Goodwill", "firstname": "James"}, 
            {"lastname": "Smith", "firstname": "Oliver"}
            ]
}
```

How do I add a new person to the array? I think I need to use JSON_ARRAY_APPEND but I can't figure out how. Name of table = person, name of column = json_col, name of array = people. I tried this and it's very close.

```
UPDATE person SET json_col = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(json_col, "$.people", "lastname":"Jonsson", "firstname":"Kurt") WHERE id = '5';
```

But this gives me an error in my SQL syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I finally did it.

```
UPDATE person SET json_col = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(json_col, '$.people', CAST('{"lastname": "Jonsson","firstname": "Kurt"}' as JSON)) WHERE id = '5';
```

This is how I append a new person into a mysql json array.

Answer (score 0):

Three steps:

1. Convert the JSON into an array
2. Push the new values into the array
3. `json_encode()` the array

Here is the code ([EXAMPLE](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9425e8008fca42926614e3fa0b88398c75410ca5)):

```
$json = '{"people": [
            {"lastname": "Goodwill", "firstname": "James"}, 
            {"lastname": "Smith", "firstname": "Oliver"}
            ]
}';

$array = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($array);

$new_person = array("lastname" => "Yo", "firstname" => "Dog");
array_push($array['people'], $new_person);

print_r($array);

$updated = json_encode($array);

echo $updated;
```

Here is the output:

```
Array
(
    [people] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [lastname] => Goodwill
                    [firstname] => James
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [lastname] => Smith
                    [firstname] => Oliver
                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [people] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [lastname] => Goodwill
                    [firstname] => James
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [lastname] => Smith
                    [firstname] => Oliver
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [lastname] => Yo
                    [firstname] => Dog
                )

        )

)
{"people":[{"lastname":"Goodwill","firstname":"James"},{"lastname":"Smith","firstname":"Oliver"},{"lastname":"Yo","firstname":"Dog"}]}
```

As long as you have the array, you can work with it until you need to output JSON.

Comment: Thanks Jay. I understand that I can do it this way but I need to know how to do this with a mysql command like JSON_ARRAY_APPEND. The datatype in mysql = JSON

Comment: If you're storing JSON in MySQL you may want to refactor the database. It really isn't a scalable idea.

Comment: Thanks Jay but my question was not about scalability. I suggest improvements.